# How to get count of first column in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to replace `count (*)` with `count(column_name)`

I am able to get the `column_name` for some `select` statements, but few are very complex and I am not able to find what are the columns returned by that `select` statement.

Is there a way where I can get `count(first_column_name)` when I am not able to find the `column name`?

Comment: You can simply change `count(*)` by `count(1)` that will also works for you

Comment: Why do you want to replace `count(*)` with `count(column_name)`? Is `column_name` nullable? Otherwise there is no difference to `*`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter aren't there any different between count(coumn_name) and count(1) ? 
i thought count(1) will return exactly same output with improved performance
http://forums.asp.net/t/1803267.aspx?What+s+the+differences+among+Count+0+Count+1+and+Count+SomeField
Sorry i am new to sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told, `COUNT(Column_Name)` can be replaced by `COUNT(n)` anytime where n = Position of the column in the dataset.

E.g. Suppose there is table `MyTable` having the below physical structure

```
EmpID|Name|Location
```

If you want to get a count of `EmpID`, use the query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MyTable
```

instead of

```
SELECT COUNT(EmpID) FROM MyTable
```

If you want a count of locations, use the query,

```
SELECT COUNT(3) FROM MyTable
```

and so on.

For the dataset `SELECT Location, EmpID, Name FROM MyTable`, to get a count of names, you need to use the query

```
SELECT COUNT(3) FROM (SELECT Location, EmpID, Name FROM MyTable)A
```